# How to initialize static function pointer with non-static class function when class initing?

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

Definition(Core.h):

```
static int (*foolink)(int*, char*, key*, key*);
```

Also redefined in Core.cpp. This code causing error:

```
foolink = this->step;
```

error:

```
Engine/Core.cpp:31: error: argument of type 'int (Core::)(int*, char*, key*, key*)' does not match 'int (*)(int*, char*, key*, key*)'
```

Pointer using:

```
(*foolink)(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

What's wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ programs, most **functions** are **member functions**; that is, they are part of a class. You are not allowed to use an ordinary **function pointer** to point to a **member function**; instead, you have to use a **member function pointer**.

In your case, you can define it as

```
     v you have to name the class here
int (YourClass::*foolink)(int*, char*, key*, key*);
foolink = &YourClass::step;

// This is how you can call the function via member function pointer
YourClass object, *pObject = &object;
// One way is to envoke the function from object
(object.*foolink)(...);
// The other way is from pointer to object
(pObject->*foolink)(...);
```

**C++ FAQ**:

[Pointers to Member Functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Comment: How can I call it? (Core::*foolink)(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) don't work!

Comment: @HiTECNOLOGYs: I'll update my answer to involve the calling of the funciton:)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `this->step` must be a function returning an integer and taking an int*, char*, key* and key* as arguments. It's obviously not. And remember, assigning class methods to normal functions won't work; they both have to be methods, or both normal functions, but not a mix, which is what I suspect you're trying to do.